# Why do some os functions ignore trailing spaces on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, directory, whitespace

I've tried the example program below on both Windows and Linux with Python 3.11.0.

```py
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":
    directory_name = "foo "
    file_name = "bar.txt"
    os.mkdir(directory_name)
    print(os.path.exists(directory_name))
    out_path = os.path.join(directory_name, file_name)
    try:
        with open(out_path, "w") as bar_file:
            pass
        print(f"Successfully opened {repr(out_path)}.")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f"Could not open {repr(out_path)}.")
    print(os.listdir())
```

The output on Linux is what I expected:

```plaintext
True
Successfully opened 'foo /bar.txt'.
['foo ']
```

However, on Windows, I get the output below.

```plaintext
True
Could not open 'foo \\bar.txt'.
['foo']
```

It seems like `os.mkdir` and `os.path.exists` are ignoring the trailing space in the directory name, but `os.path.join` is not.

Why do these methods behave this way on Windows? Is the behavior intentional? Moreover, what is the best way to overcome this discrepancy and get the same behavior on both systems?

Comment: Note: As per the windows file [naming convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#naming-conventions) *Do not end a file or directory name with a space or a period. Although the underlying file system may support such names, the Windows shell and user interface does not*

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM To add some more context—I'm fetching files from a source where some directories have trailing spaces, and I would like to preserve the directory names if I can. It sounds like picking a different name is usually better choice, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, trailing spaces are generally allowed, but they may be automatically trimmed in some contexts.

The observed behavior is likely due to the underlying implementation of these functions in the operating system. The `os.mkdir` function and `os.path.exists` function may be using the Windows API function [CreateDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createdirectorya), which [ignores trailing spaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.createdirectory?view=net-7.0) (see remarks in that hyperlink) in the directory name when creating a new directory. The `os.path.join` function, on the other hand, may be using string manipulation to concatenate the directory name and file name, which does not automatically trim the trailing space. You may consider browsing [os source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/os.py) to be certain of the later part.

To get consistent behavior on both Windows and Linux, you can trim any trailing spaces from the directory name before using it in these functions. (using `rstrip` for example):

`directory_name = directory_name.rstrip()`

Comment: It looks like [CPython calls CreateDirectoryW](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b6bd7ffcbc1ffaa68e3423e7415ef8ba0f8a188d/Modules/posixmodule.c#L4539) in the Windows implementation of mkdir, so I think you may be right that Win32 API is responsible for the behavior. The approach you suggest seems good in general. It's not ideal for my specific purposes, but I didn't specify that in the question. I'll accept your answer.

Comment: hmm. As it's ill-advised to have the trailing spaces (they're invisible afterall), it's a good time to clean it up. I can see your issue doesn't exist if you are on a linux system and running the code. You can do a check if the directory name has spaces at the end and if so, rename that directory. The rest of the code will be fine. If you absolutely must keep the spaces  but still want to open the text file, I'm still not sure how to do that. I don't have a windows system to test with. Do update here if you find a solution to that though and it can be added to the answer to help future users.

Comment: for instance you can do `if directory_name != directory_name.rsrtip(): os.rename(directory_name, directory_name.rstip())`. I'm again assuming you're ok with the name change, or your hesititation in changing the names is because it affects whether or not the rest of the code will run on it. But after renaming the directory, the rest of the code where you access any files contained within it should run just fine.

Comment: The actual task I'm doing is further removed than I realized from the MCVE I tried to make. I had hoped someone would have some elegant cross-platform way of allowing spaces in directory names and didn't consider that "just don't do that" might be a reasonable answer to the exact question I asked.

Comment: I eventually intend to run my real code on Linux, but I'm testing on a Windows machine. I'm hesitant to change names for a few reasons. One is that some files I'm grabbing might contain text that refers to certain directory names—e.g., if I'm downloading a python script, it might break if I rename files or directories. Another is that there may be directories that clash with the name I get when doing `rstrip`. I could find another name in the event of a conflict, but I'd prefer to do it systematically. Frankly, that's a bit of a pain, so I might just move to Linux for now.